# Linear Algebra linear transformation and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T\colon V \to V$ be linear.
Assume that $V = R(T) + N(T)$,
Then $R(T) \cap N(T) = \{0\}$.

One solution I saw online involves 
$$\begin{align*}
\dim(R(T) + N(T)) & = \dim R(T) + \dim N(T) − \dim(R(T) \cap N(T))
\\ & = \dim R(T) + \dim N(T) 
\\ & = \dim V.\end{align*}$$

But I do not understand this part:
$$\dim(R(T) + N(T)) = \dim R(T) + \dim N(T) − \dim(R(T) \cap N(T)).$$

Can somebody explain to me why this is so? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Grassmann's formula states that if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, then
$$\dim (U + W) + \dim (U \cap W) = \dim U + \dim W.$$
In your case, the formula was used with $U = R(T)$ and $W = N(T)$.

If you have never seen a proof of this formula, you can try to prove it yourself. *Hint*: Fix a basis of $U \cap W$, and consider bases of $U$ and $W$ that contain the basis of $U \cap W$.